# How to use strtolower in *.blade.php file with @lang extension in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, laravel-localization

I have tried this, but get error:

```
{{ strtolower( @lang('basics.days') ) }}
```

How can I transform to lowercase my localized string in a `.blade.php` file in `Laravel` 5.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`trans()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-trans) helper:

```
{{ strtolower(trans('basics.days')) }}
```